# How to use periodic tasks with django-celery-beat in two Django projects sharing the same database

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I have two Django projects sharing the same PostgreSQL database. `Celery` and `django-celery-beat` application are created and installed in both projects.

The problem is that periodic tasks from one project are detected by the Celery application of the other project as unregistered and `REJECTED`. I believe the `django-celery-beat` of both projects share the same tables of the database.

I came to this conclusion because both projects are containerized, they have their own Docker network and redis server listening on 2 different ports number. Finally, both projects have a dedicated default queue name.

What is the best way to address the issue ? I'm relatively new with Django but I think each project should have a dedicated `django-celery-beat` application. Can I do that with `AppConfig` and then create new tables with `migrate` ?

The naming could be something like :

settings.py (project A)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_celery_beat_project_a',
    ...
]
```

settings.py (project B)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_celery_beat_project_b',
    ...
]
```

**Output**

```
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974463294Z Received unregistered task of type 'trading.tasks.bulk_trade'.
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974621504Z The message has been ignored and discarded.
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974655749Z 
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974677303Z Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974699464Z Or maybe you're using relative imports?
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974721029Z 
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974741804Z Please see
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974782954Z http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974815238Z for more information.
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974839132Z 
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974897495Z The full contents of the message body was:
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974938229Z b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.974982482Z 
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.975032349Z Thw full contents of the message headers:
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.975090058Z {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'trading.tasks.bulk_trade', 'id': 'd86620c2-04ab-4b59-bb2e-77685389f8d5', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': 'd86620c2-04ab-4b59-bb2e-77685389f8d5', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': '()', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen9@03298c28290e', 'ignore_result': False}
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.975125751Z 
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.975194550Z The delivery info for this task is:
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.975257110Z {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'project-a_queue_1'}
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.981241271Z  exc_info=(<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('trading.tasks.bulk_trade'), <traceback object at 0x7fe49ca1b8c0>)
project-a-celery_worker-1  | 2022-09-09T11:35:15.996976839Z [error    ] task_not_found                              [django_structlog.celery.receivers] message=<Message object at 0x7fe49cb6e680 with details {'state': 'REJECTED', 'content_type': 'application/json', 'delivery_tag': '43925569-3d7a-4272-9629-2e08581f6579', 'body_length': 77, 'properties': {'correlation_id': 'd86620c2-04ab-4b59-bb2e-77685389f8d5'}, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'project-a_queue_1'}}>
```

Comment: what about replacing the `autodiscover_tasks` with `include` arg (in `Celery` init). Did you try that to see if it makes a different?

Comment: Hi @ItayB I just figured out that the issue comes fom the `django-celery-beat` application that share the same tables of the database in both project. Consequence is that a periodic task from one project is detected by the other project unregistered and `REJECTED`. I'm going to update the question

Answer (score 0):

I finally came to a solution and the problem is fixed. This is how to proceed.

Delete all periodic tasks.

Rename `django_celery_beat` in all the Python packages, I did it from the Dockerfile :

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

RUN find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/django_celery_beat/django_celery_beat_project_a/g' \
    && sed -i "126 i \ \ \ \ name = 'django_celery_beat_trader.schedulers' if name == 'django_celery_beat.schedulers' else name" /usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py \
    && cp -r django_celery_beat django_celery_beat_project_a
```

Rename the application in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_celery_beat_project_a',
    ...
]
```

Write the new tables in the database:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```